# Adding a Legend in R map graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, maps, legend

i have the following map, which was built from the data on the library "maps".

it is basically the distance among all counties at USA and some important airports, the thing is that I haven't been able to add a legend, I know it is because my mapping doesn't involve the variable color, I'm new in ggplot, how can I add the legend with the colors (which represent the airports).

i want to add something like this:  Graph + legend (Title="Airports",fill = color, names=c("MIA","JFK","LAX","IAH","ORD","DFW","ATL") )

by the way, if you know where I can find the same data to create a USA map but with zip codes instead of counties would be great!

here is my result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiUWt.png)

Thank you! here is the code i have been using:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

AllCounty <- map_data("county")
MainStates <- map_data("state")
#defining coordinates for airports
miaAirport = data.frame(rep(25.7933,87949 ),rep(-80.2906,87949))
jfkAirport = data.frame(rep(40.641766,87949 ),rep(-73.780968,87949))
laxAirport = data.frame(rep(33.942791,87949),rep(-118.410042,87949))
IahAirport = data.frame(rep(29.9902,87949),rep(-95.3367,87949))
OrdAirport = data.frame(rep(41.978611,87949),rep(-87.904724,87949))
DfwAirport = data.frame(rep(32.897480,87949),rep(-97.040443,87949))
AtlAirport = data.frame(rep(33.640411,87949),rep(-84.419853,87949))

names(miaAirport) = c("lat","long")
names(jfkAirport) = c("lat","long")
names(laxAirport) = c("lat","long")
names(IahAirport) = c("lat","long")
names(OrdAirport) = c("lat","long")
names(DfwAirport) = c("lat","long")
names(AtlAirport) = c("lat","long")
#distances
difMia = sqrt(((miaAirport$lat-AllCounty$lat)^2)+((miaAirport$long-AllCounty$long)^2))
difJfk = sqrt(((jfkAirport$lat-AllCounty$lat)^2)+((jfkAirport$long-AllCounty$long)^2))
difLax = sqrt(((laxAirport$lat-AllCounty$lat)^2)+((laxAirport$long-AllCounty$long)^2))
difIah = sqrt(((IahAirport$lat-AllCounty$lat)^2)+((IahAirport$long-AllCounty$long)^2))
difOrd = sqrt(((OrdAirport$lat-AllCounty$lat)^2)+((OrdAirport$long-AllCounty$long)^2))
difDfw = sqrt(((DfwAirport$lat-AllCounty$lat)^2)+((DfwAirport$long-AllCounty$long)^2))
difAtl = sqrt(((AtlAirport$lat-AllCounty$lat)^2)+((AtlAirport$long-AllCounty$long)^2))


AllCounty$MIA = difMia
AllCounty$JFK = difJfk
AllCounty$LAX = difLax
AllCounty$IAH = difIah
AllCounty$ORD = difOrd
AllCounty$DFW = difDfw
AllCounty$ATL = difAtl
attach(AllCounty)
Mins = apply(data.frame(MIA,JFK,LAX,IAH,ORD,DFW,ATL), 1, FUN=min)

for (i in 1:87949) {
  if(AllCounty$LAX[i] == Mins[i]){AllCounty$color[i]="#CC79A7"}
          else if(AllCounty$JFK[i] == Mins[i]){AllCounty$color[i]="#999999"}
          else if(AllCounty$IAH[i] == Mins[i]){AllCounty$color[i]="#F0E442"}  
          else if(AllCounty$ORD[i] == Mins[i]){AllCounty$color[i]="#009E73"}
          else if(AllCounty$DFW[i] == Mins[i]){AllCounty$color[i]="#56B4E9"}
          else if(AllCounty$ATL[i] == Mins[i]){AllCounty$color[i]="#D55E00"}  
          else{AllCounty$color[i]="#0072B2"}
}
ggplot() + geom_polygon( data=AllCounty, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
                         color="black", fill=AllCounty$color, size = .1 )+
  geom_polygon( data=MainStates, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
                color="white",  size = .05, alpha = .1) +
  ggtitle("Nearest international airport to each location at USA") +
  labs(x="Longitude",y="Latitude")
```

Comment: If you want a legend, then the `fill=` should be inside the `aes()`.So  use ` aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=color)` and then add `+ scale_fill_identity()` to let ggplot know you are providing actual RGB values. You can set the labels you like with `labels=` in the scale function.

Comment: Take a look at the “geosphere” package to correctly calculate the distance between two geographic coordinates.

Comment: I tried your proposal but still it doesnt show legend:ggplot() + geom_polygon( data=AllCounty, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group,fill=color),
                         color="black" , size = .1 )+
  geom_polygon( data=MainStates, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
                color="white",  size = .05, alpha = .1) +
  ggtitle("Nearest international airport to each location at USA") +
  labs(x="Longitude",y="Latitude")+
  scale_fill_identity(labels=c("LAX","ATL","JFK","IAH","ORD","DFW","ATL"))

Comment: By default `scale_fill_identity` will not show a legend. If you want the legend to show up add argument `guide = "legend"`

Comment: Got it, thank you so much for your help.